# How to make login page code with multiple users simpler?

Tags: vb.net

In VB.NET project, I'm trying to create a login page which users could login using a form. I used an array to save the login information. However, it's complicated when verifying, and thus I cannot add a user simply by adding item to array. I'll need to add a `else if` in the code, so it's very inconvenient.

The code is below :

```
Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
    Dim UserNameAvailable As Integer = 0
    Dim UsernameList(2) As String
    Dim PasswordList(2) As String
    UsernameList(0) = "jamiechoi"
    PasswordList(0) = "198237645"
    UsernameList(1) = "marcoyeung"
    PasswordList(1) = "infotalkong"
    UsernameList(2) = "user"
    PasswordList(2) = "toolbox"
    Dim InputUsername As String
    InputUsername = UsernameTextBox.Text
    Dim InputPassword As String
    InputPassword = PasswordTextBox.Text
    If InputUsername = UsernameList(0) Then
        If InputPassword = PasswordList(0) Then
            Me.Hide()
            AdminArea.Show()
            UserNameAvailable = 1
        Else
            MsgBox("Wrong Password!")
            UserNameAvailable = 1
        End If
    ElseIf InputUsername = UsernameList(1) Then
        If InputPassword = PasswordList(1) Then
            Me.Hide()
            AdminArea.Show()
            UserNameAvailable = 1
        Else
            MsgBox("Wrong Password!")
            UserNameAvailable = 1
        End If
    ElseIf InputUsername = UsernameList(2) Then
        If InputPassword = PasswordList(2) Then
            Me.Hide()
            AdminArea.Show()
            UserNameAvailable = 1
        Else
            MsgBox("Wrong Password!")
            UserNameAvailable = 1
        End If
    End If

    If UserNameAvailable = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Wrong Username!")
    End If
End Sub
```

I hope that I could use a `for` loop to complete the verifying task. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for answering so late (and didn't accept the answer) because the result of answer was unexpected.

This is my expected solution :

(Something like)

```
For i As Integer = 1 To UsernameList.Length
    If InputUsername = UsernameList(i) AndAlso InputPassword = PasswordList(i) Then
        Me.Hide()
        AdminArea.Show()
    End If
Next
```

And that's my solution.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is just a programming exercise and not a real-world application (at least I hope so) so I won't get deep into the whole *never-hardcode-secret-informations-in-your-code*-thing.

---

Usernames and passwords have a 1-to-1 relationship (each username has one password), so it's sensible to express that in code.

The easiest way is to use a `Dictionary` to create a mapping username->password. Then we can use `TryGetValue` to check if the username exists and retrieve the password:

```
Private Sub OK_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
    Dim credentials = New Dictionary(Of String, String) From _
    {
        {"jamiechoi", "198237645"},
        {"marcoyeung", "infotalkong"},
        {"user", "toolbox"}
    }

    Dim passwd As String
    If credentials.TryGetValue(UsernameTextBox.Text, passwd) AndAlso passwd = PasswordTextBox.Text Then
        Me.Hide()
        AdminArea.Show()
    Else
        MsgBox("Wrong User/Password!")
    End If

End Sub
```

Note that in a real-world-application you would not store the usernames/passwords in code, but in e.g. a database, and also you would just store a salted hash of the password, not the plaintext.

Comment: I know it, but after publishing this program, will anybody be able to check this code?

Comment: Is there a way to use array but make it simpler?

Comment: @Jamie *will anybody be able to check this code?* Yes. It can be decompiled.

Comment: @Jamie *The result is many errors!!! What shall i do??* You could start by saying what errors you get.

Comment: @Jamie *Is there a way to use array but make it simpler?* Yes. But this is the simplest and cleanest way. Why messing around with an array?

Comment: http://s29.postimg.org/ivw9on3s5/screenshot.jpg Just check this one. You'll see what error occur.

Comment: The dictionary initiliazer syntax is not supported in your version of VB.Net. Either use a recent version (like Visual Studio 2012 or 2013) or remove the `From` clause and simple add the data to the `Dictionary` using the `Add` method.

Comment: Oh, I see. __SO__, what's the code using array but simpler?

Answer (score 0):

here is my little correction to the code:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To UsernameList.Length - 1
    If InputUsername = UsernameList(i) AndAlso InputPassword = PasswordList(i) Then
        Me.Hide()
        AdminArea.Show()
    End If
Next
```